# ColdFusion alternative for PHP md5 function

Tags: php, coldfusion, md5, coldfusion-8, hmac

I have tried to HMAC MD5 implementation in Coldfusion. I am having PHP code for the same. I would like find out the best way to convert the same into ColdFusion.

***PHP***

```
  $output = hmac($key, $str);

  function hmac ($key, $data)
  {
    // RFC 2104 HMAC implementation for php.
    // Creates an md5 HMAC.
    // Eliminates the need to install mhash to compute a HMAC

    $b = 64; // byte length for md5
    if (strlen($key) > $b) {
      $key = pack("H*",md5($key));
    }
    $key  = str_pad($key, $b, chr(0x00));
    $ipad = str_pad('', $b, chr(0x36));
    $opad = str_pad('', $b, chr(0x5c));
    $k_ipad = $key ^ $ipad ;
    $k_opad = $key ^ $opad;

    return md5($k_opad  . pack("H*",md5($k_ipad . $data)));
  }
```

I have tried the following in code in ColdFusion.

***ColdFusion***

```
  <cfset outputOld = hmacEncrypt(key, input, 'HmacMD5') />
  <cfset output = binaryEncode(outputOld, 'hex') />

  <cffunction name="hmacEncrypt" returntype="binary" access="public" output="false">
    <cfargument name="signKey" type="string" required="true" />
    <cfargument name="signMessage" type="string" required="true" />
    <cfargument name="algorithm" type="string" default="HmacMD5" />
    <cfargument name="charset" type="string" default="UTF-8" />

    <cfset var msgBytes = charsetDecode(arguments.signMessage, arguments.charset) />
    <cfset var keyBytes = charsetDecode(arguments.signKey, arguments.charset) />
    <cfset var keySpec = createObject("java","javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec")  />
    <cfset var mac = createObject("java","javax.crypto.Mac") />

    <cfset key = keySpec.init(keyBytes, arguments.algorithm) />
    <cfset mac = mac.getInstance(arguments.algorithm) />
    <cfset mac.init(key) />
    <cfset mac.update(msgBytes) />

    <cfreturn mac.doFinal() />
  </cffunction>
```

But I am getting different values for PHP and ColdFusion. I need to get the same as PHP.

Any help is much appreicated.

Comment: What is the actual question here?

Comment: Specifically how are you "getting different values"? A few quick tests seemed to work fine for me (CF11). The only difference I noticed is CF's result is in upper case, and php in lower, but you can easily change that result with lcase().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I strongly recommend you use the [Crypto.cfc](https://github.com/bennadel/Crypto.cfc) by [Bennadel](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2412-crypto-cfc-for-hmac-sha1-hmac-sha256-and-hmac-md5-code-generation-in-coldfusion.htm).It provides methods for generating Hmac values with the SHA-1, SHA-256, and MD5 algorithms and is very cleanly written.

Also, I would prefer to use the `hash_hmac()` function available in PHP for it's performance and simplicity.

```
string hash_hmac('md5', $input, $secretKey);
```

As far as I can understand, you're comparing a string output with a binary output, which won't match. `md5` returns a string output but the `doFinal()` in `javax.crypto.Mac` returns a `byte[]` representation. You need to typecast accordingly. Correct it and the result is the same.

### Update

You can check the base code in both the language:

[ColdFusion Code](http://trycf.com/gist/4da625db07d730198ab3/acf11?theme=monokai)

[PHP Code](http://phpfiddle.org/lite/code/411cb5ef0560be3e8441)

As you can see, the results are the same. Dude, it's your code only and it's working fine with the addition of only `lcase` as pointed by [@Leigh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/104223/leigh).

Comment: Yes bro, That also giving me a different output. The above coldFusion code and bennadal's code gives same output. I think both are logically same. But I need the same which is getting from my PHP code.

Comment: try hash_hmac() function available in PHP. It's working for me along with the Crypto.cfc

Comment: You may be correct. But the problem is, I want to convert PHP code to ColdFusion code. That's why I need the alternative of the above PHP code. The encrypted value which is getting from PHP section is the exact one. I need the same in ColdFusion.

Comment: Did you tried it? I said I ran the code against the changes I made, it is getting me the same data both in php and in coldfusion.

Comment: But I am getting a different one. Hope the above change to convert binary to string is fine? Can I know the key value that you have given?

Comment: The key value doesn't matter as long you are passing the same to both `PHP` and `ColdFusion`. For the reference I passed "TheMinions are back".

Comment: (Edit typo) @lambypie - *How* is it different? Please post an example with a dummy key. Like Anurag said, [the results of the original code](http://trycf.com/gist/7b7e8921a969ddcbd315/acf11?theme=monokai) look the same as far as I can see. The only difference being that CF's converts the string to upper case, which you can fix by using lcase().

Comment: Oh. Its was a mistake drs. Thanks for your effort. In my PHP code, the key is passed as hexa decimal string. I also passed the same by converting it into hexadecimal in ColdFusion by binaryDecode function. I removed it and working fine.